# Array index out of bounds in Array with arbitrary index bounds

Tags: c#, arrays

I Wrote a class which allows users to set a bottom bound of array, in instance "myArray(-5, 10)" where -5 start index and 10 length of array. But I am getting an error when I compare i <= myArray.GetArrayLength. What I did wrong. I will appriciated any help.

```
using System;

namespace UsArrClass
{
    class Program
    {

        class UserArr 
        {
            private int[] _UsArr;
            private int _start;
            private int _len;

            public int[] UsArr
            {
                get => this._UsArr;
                set => this._UsArr = value;
            }
            public int BotomBoundary
            {
                get => this._start;
                set => this._start = value;
            }
            public int TopBoundary => (GetUserArrLength -1) + BotomBoundary;

            public int GetUserArrLength => _len;


            public UserArr(int start, int len)
            {
                this.BotomBoundary = start;
                this._len = len;
                UsArr = new int [len];
            }

            public int this[int n]
            {
                get => UsArr[n - BotomBoundary];
                set => UsArr[n - BotomBoundary] = value;
            }


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                UserArr myarr = new UserArr( 0, 3);

                for (int i = myarr.BotomBoundary; i <= myarr.GetUserArrLength; i++)
                {
                    myarr[i] = i;
                    Console.Write(" "+ myarr[i]);

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(myarr.TopBoundary);
                Console.WriteLine(myarr[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(myarr.BotomBoundary);
                Console.WriteLine(myarr.GetUserArrLength);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `i < myarr.GetUserArrLength`

Comment: I know it works if so, But normal array I can compare with it self Length.

Comment: Array indices are from 0 to length - 1. you can compare with the length, but there is nothing in `arr[arr.Length]`

Comment: Thanks friends, I probably mixed something up;) tired